# uiimage not being put into subview correctly

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiimageview

This is a difficult problem to explain... but i'll do my best.
First a background on the problem, basically i am creating a paint like app for ios and wanted to add a functionality that allows the user to select part of the image (multi-touch shows an opaque rectangle) and delete/copy-paste/rotate that part. I have got the delete and copy-paste working perfectly but the rotation is another story. To rotate the part of the image I first start by copying the part of the image and setting it to be the background of the selected rectangle layer, then the user rotates by an arbitrary angle using a slider. The problem is that sometimes the image ends up being displayed from another location of the rectangle (meaning the copied image hangs off the wrong corner of the rectangle). I thought this could be a problem with my rectangle.frame.origin but the value for that seems to be correct through various tests. It also seems to change depending on the direction that the drag goes in...

**These Are Screens of the problem**

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

In each of the above cases the mismatched part of the image should be inside the grey rectangle, i am at a loss as to what the problem is.

```
     bg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self crop:rectangle.frame:drawImage.image]];
     [rectangle addSubview:bg];
```

drawImage is the users drawing, and rectangle is the selected grey area.
crop is a method which returns a part of a given image from a give rect.

I am also having trouble with pasting an arbitrarily rotated image.. any ideas on how to do that?

Edit: adding more code.

```
    -(void)drawRect:(int)x1:(int)y1:(int)x2:(int)y2{
     [rectangle removeFromSuperview];
     rectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1)]; 
     rectangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.9 green:0.9 blue:0.9 alpha:0.6];
     selectionImage = drawImage.image;
     drawImage.image = selectionImage;
     [drawImage addSubview:rectangle];
     rectangleVisible = true;
     rectangle.transform = transformation;
```

Could it have anything to do with how i draw my rectangle? (above) I call this method from a part of a touchesMoved method (below) which may cause the problem (touch 1 being in the wrong location may cause width to be negative?) if so, is there an easy way to remedy this?

```
     if([[event allTouches] count] == 2 && !drawImage.hidden){
        NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
        UITouch *touch1 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        UITouch *touch2 = [[allTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
        [self drawRect:[touch1 locationInView:drawImage].x :[touch1 locationInView:drawImage].y:
        [touch2 locationInView:drawImage].x :[touch2 locationInView:drawImage].y];   
     }
```

Comment: I think you need to add quite a bit more code here to aid in people understanding of your question!

Comment: I agree, just had to think about which part to add. I think the part I added might be the root of the problem

Comment: That said about adding code, putting all the images above is a great start! It means you spend a bit (large bit) of time to provide information to people trying to help - very good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but it looks like you are just assuming that touch1 represents the upper left touch. I would start out by standardizing the rectangle.

```
// Standardizing the rectangle before making it the frame.
CGRect frame = CGRectStandardize(CGRectMake(x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1));
rectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that could be the problem but didn't know it was a 1 line fix